# How do I validate user input in a Prism 6.3 WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am trying to write a WPF application using c# and the with the help of [Prism 6.3 library](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism). I watched all available tutorials on [pluralsight.com](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/search?q=prism) for Prism by @BrianLagunas . But not of them show how to do data validation.

I need to add input validation before I submit the data to the database.

How can I add validation rule, and how can I check if the form is valid before I save the data to the database?

Comment: Anything preventing you from adding a validation rule to your bindings? Nothing prism specific here, unless I miss something.

Comment: @Haukinger what do you mean by adding the rule to the bindings?

Comment: I'm talking about plain old wpf binding validation, I've put an example and a bit of explanation in my answer

Comment: Unfortunately, input validation is out of scope for an introductory course to Prism. Since you have pluralsight, I recommend the following course which will cover what you are looking for. https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/wpf-data-binding-in-depth/table-of-contents

Answer (score 0):

You are look for **[MvvmValidation](https://github.com/pglazkov/mvvmvalidation)**.
I think the library satisfy your needs.
Go and have a try, it has some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Simple wpf binding validation might work here.

Given this code from a view's xaml:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Data">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <myNamespace:IntegerValidationRule/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

and this rule

```
public class IntegerValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate( object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo )
    {
        var stringData = value as string;
        if( stringData == null )
            return new ValidationResult( false, "not a string" );
        int dummy;
        if( !int.TryParse( stringData, out dummy ) )
            return new ValidationResult( false, "not an integer" );
        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

you'll get a nice red border around the text box if you enter something that's not an integer. And, more importantly, the view model's `Data` property setter won't be called.

If you need complex validation (i.e. no single property value is valid, but only a combination of values of differnet properties), then your view model needs to implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo`. You basically do your validation in any of the affected properties' setters and finally raise `ErrorsChanged`...